# Close vote hammer for migrations?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, migration

This is a really simple question and feature request. We now have the "close vote hammer" for duplicate questions, which is really helpful for quickly cleaning up duplicates by granting privileges to trusted users within a tag. Can we do something similar for migrations?

**My feature request**: Give users who've voted enough times on (successful/correct) migrations to a specific site additional powers to migrate off-topic questions to more appropriate SE sites. This would be site-specific, and based on past voting for migrations. It could be a single-vote hammer, but it could also be more than one vote on these migrations (vote counts double or triple), or something similar.

**Some background context**: I'm coming at this from the perspective of the [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex) tag. Many, many of the questions here eventually get migrated to [TeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). It seems that there are very few users on SO who regularly monitor this tag, so it's me and [Werner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/914686/werner) and a few other people who frequently end up initiating migrations, nearly all of which are eventually migrated. A lot of these questions would be answered very quickly on TeX but don't get answered quickly here on SO. A quicker migration might get these questions more attention from the users at TeX that can answer them most effectively, while also cleaning up SO a little bit.

Comment: I'm not sure if many of the regulars in the [SO Close vote reviewers room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) have experience in those tags but you could try to leave a cv-pls there for specific questions.

Comment: You should need close vote privileges on the target site in order to unlock elevated migration privileges, imo.

Comment: @rene: That goes counter to the spirit of this request, which is to favor the opinion of those who understand the other site, as evidenced either by having gotten it right in the past, or as in Bill's comment, being a privileged member on the other site.

Comment: @BenVoigt This is the second time today I'm lectured about migrations. I rage quit, OK?

Comment: Seconded, on the basis of SO -> CrossValidated migration (which I do a lot of; I don't know how to access my migration stats, but I have 63K on SO under the [r] tag and 6K on CV ...) (PS triple-vote seems to make sense to me, if it's not too hard to implement -- that means two hammer-privileged users or one hammer-privileged  + 2 non-privileged users would put it over the top)

Comment: Given that there is a TeX SE, shouldn't the `latex` tag simple be retired on SO?

Comment: @RolandSmith No, because there are lots of programming questions that have LaTeX implications (e.g., programming questions that are meant to produce LaTeX output belong here), or the use of pandoc to translate to/from LaTeX.

Comment: @Thomas I get that. But producing LaTeX code isn't really all *that* hard. It is basically a question of which LaTeX special characters are also special in your string formatting syntax and how do you escape them. And AFAICT it is not what most LaTeX questions are about.