# Allow OP to accept migration/off-topic close reason

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

We have a way to allow the OP to close their question as a duplicate if they agree.

It would be nice if we had the same capability for migrations or other off-topic reasons.

This user here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992332/iis-8-configure-virtual-directory-with-forward-slash flagged it as such, but no action was taken.

This is similar to [Close vote hammer for migrations?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289987/close-vote-hammer-for-migrations), but to allow the OP to bang the hammer.

Comment: I disagree for migrations. I would rather have 2-3 3k (minimum) users redirect a post for migrations. I would not leave it up to the OP, who might not be as high a level.

Answer (score 7):

Just because they're the OP doesn't mean that they're a good judge of whether their question would be on topic at the target site.

In the proposal you link to, the people being given the hammer have a track record of successful migrations. The OP may have never been to the target migration site or be familiar with their rules. It doesn't make sense to give them the ability to speed up a migration.

Comment: They may not be the best judge regarding the target site, but a clean migration might be better than having them ask a copy of the question there anyway, instead of having to wait for 5 votes (the time to wait can vary greatly). It sometimes lead to two sets of answers (especially when the questions are not referenced across site). I've seen that a few times for questions on SO that were more appropriate on Security.SE.

Comment: @Bruno - What I've been told and have seen repeated on Meta is that the policy is to not migrate "garbage". If a site attempts to migrate a question to another site and the mods there know that the question would/should get closed they won't accept it.

Comment: Sure, a bad quality question shouldn't be migrated, I'm just talking about a question that would be acceptable on the target site. Anyway, the question mentioned on this Meta question looks reasonable and on-topic to me.

Comment: *I'm just talking about a question that would be acceptable on the target site.* @Bruno - Yes, but acceptable according to who? The proposal is to allow the OP to bypass the requirement for other votes. If it's not the OP deciding whether the question is acceptable in this scenario then who is? Am I misunderstanding something about the migration process in this proposal?

Comment: Independently of the actual subject, you can often judge from the structure and clarity of the question whether it seems a reasonable question. In many cases, close/migration votes are accompanied with comments saying "you should ask this on Other Site instead" (or something along these lines, in which case the OP will often ask there straight away (whether it's suitable there or not, so subject to potential closure on the target site anyway). My point is that quick migration at least prevents cross-site duplicates, which can be left open on both sites for a while.

Comment: @Bruno - It would only result in faster migrations if the questions actually get migrated. What it will probably result in is a flood of bad content in the direction of mods on other SE sites. In fact, it could result in other sites [asking to be removed from the migration list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators). I'm also not sure that cross-site duplication is a problem worth solving, esp. since there's overlap in topicality in SE sites.