# Suggest posting to TeX when tagging question with LaTeX, etc

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, asking-questions, tag-tips

Would it be possible to have a "tag suggestion" when users post a [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex) or [tex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tex) question without a major language tag that points them to post on [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) instead. Inevitably, questions that are only about LaTeX (and not about, for example, creating a LaTeX document from [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and [knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knitr)) are much better suited to the TeX StackExchange than to StackOverflow (and [are eventually migrated there anyway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289987/close-vote-hammer-for-migrations)).

What I have in mind is something like the pop-up for using the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag by itself:

[image]

The text could read something like:

> Questions that are exclusively about TeX, LaTeX, and related typesetting systems are more appropriately asked on [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) unless they involve a broader programming problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Oh, fine.

[image: Questions about the use and syntax of TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems often do better on TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange - check it out!]

There's no easy way to check for the presence of these tags without another tag, so this'll just pop up every time someone uses them now. C'est la vie.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hopefully people will read it and actually post it there instead.

Comment: There are 5 offtopic questions each day in [tag:latex] - actually I see about 80 % being so. The new banner does not seem to be prominent enough - in fact it can take a second or two to load so people can actually hit submit before it is read. Perhaps there should be an acknowledgment required from new users to these prompts .