# Would a pop-up whenever using [latex] be beneficial?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-tips

I have been reviewing [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex) every now and then lately. What I have noticed is that most questions concerning LaTeX are purely about LaTeX. This prompts of course the reviewer to choose Off-Topic -> Migration -> http://text.stackexchange.com. However, a lot of questions are just code dumps, or of low quality so they should not be moved at all. Possibly there will be a duplicate around on tex.SE as well, but having never used the site myself I can't determine that.

Questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563096/why-there-is-no-space-between-multiple-references-want-1-2-instead-of-1-2 should probably be migrated, but a question such as [LaTeX to RTF conversion including citations and figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563634/latex-to-rtf-conversion-including-citations-and-figures) actually combines LaTeX with another programming language and should be kept on Stack Overflow.

Therefore my question: would it be beneficial to spawn a pop-up whenever a user tries to ask a question with [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex) tagged that says `There is a dedicated stack exchange site for LaTeX at http://tex.stackexchange.com`? Which can possibly paired with a filter to check on whether a programming language such as the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) as on the above question is attached.

Comment: So... Are these questions _off-topic_ on Stack Overflow to begin with? Because you should only be trying to migrate questions that have no place here to begin with- That a dedicated site exists does not make the questions off-topic here.

Comment: @Kendra *pure* LaTeX questions are off-topic, hence the migration reason. I also gave an example of a question which should not be migrated, as it combines another programming language with LaTeX and is probably more of an R problem than a LaTeX problem. Regardless of the on-topicness of pure LaTeX questions I think they'd get more help on tex.SE, since all the avid LaTeX users will check there more often than the [latex] on SO.

Comment: I honestly don't use either TeX or LaTeX, so will have to take the word of others on the matter, but it's an important point. The wiki for the tag does mention [discussions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7135/where-should-a-question-about-latex-usage-go) on [whether](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stack-overflow) these questions can go on Stack Overflow. The discussions there seem to say these _are_ still on-topic here. There's likely more questions here on MSO about it as well, they're just not in the wiki.

Comment: Looks like this [came up late last year](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303245/suggest-posting-to-tex-when-tagging-question-with-latex-etc) and appears to have gotten little to no attention.

Comment: @Kendra I completely missed that in my search on meta. Good find