# Is it recommended to suggest another site in an answer?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday, two of my answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70410582/14036406), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70410987/14036406)) were downvoted. I am trying to find the reason and edit the answers accordingly.

I don't think there was any problem with the approaches suggested in the answers. They contained MWE and output. The only reason that came to my mind for downvoting was my suggestion to post such question in [TEX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) which some users might find inappropriate.

So, is it recommended or not to provide such suggestions in answers? I have seen such suggestions in comments but can't remember seeing any in answers.

Comment: I, personally, wouldn't say that because there is another site that is dedicated to the language isn't a reason to downvote, but that doesn't mean that others don't. The true fact, however, is we don't know why the answer was downvoted unless the voter states; and they are under no requirement to do so. It could be just as likely that the user did fell the answer wasn't useful/helpful as they are fluent in Latex and could make that judgement (note I know knowing on the technology, so can't make such a comment).

Comment: Being a non TeX-user, I can't assess the quality of the answer, but such remark is usually considered as meta-commentary and doesn't belong to the post. TeX is on-topic on SO, and [askers are already pointed to TeX.SE when they use 'latex' tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338027/2821954) (nowadays, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXXB0.png))

Comment: I didn't find any mention of TeX.SE in the linked answer 2. Did I miss something?

Comment: No, you didn't miss anything. It was mentioned in one answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some things of note:

- Just because another site exists, the question doesn't automatically become off-topic here. There are overlapping scopes with a whole lot of sites. I don't see how these questions you linked would be off-topic here.
- There might be another site *more suitable*, but that isn't a reason for down-voting or close-voting. Recommendations for other more suitable sites should be posted as comments to the question, rather than in an answer. But that alone shouldn't be a reason for down-voting.
- In case a question is definitely off-topic here, you could post a comment telling where the question belongs. In such cases, the question should be closed and not answered. Answering off-topic questions would be a reason for down votes.

So I don't see any reason why these posts should be down-voted because of the site recommendation.

Now as for why they were down-voted anyway, it could be because of errors in the technical content (I can't tell) or that it fails to answer the question (I can't tell) or simply because voting is subjective. There are lots of weird votes cast all the time and they aren't always justified.

Comment: Another possible reason could that the voter(s) agreed that the question belongs to another site and wanted to improve the chances for roomba to delete the Q/A by preventing a positive answer. A far fetched reason, but still possible.

Comment: Thanks. I won't recommend other sites in answers in the future.

Comment: @Imran I'm a regular at TeX.SE, and of course we would like it if you recommend the site - but if you do that then maybe not answer on SO, and instead wait until it is indeed posted on TeX.SE, and then answer there yourself (if it is not low-quality or a duplicate of course).

Comment: The technical content seems fine to me by the way, and it also answers the question. The code is a bit difficult to read (if you would align the `&` symbols in the source as well it would be easier) and the answer does not contain much explanation on how and why this works, which may have been reasons to downvote - but on TeX.SE this answer would definitely not be downvoted, we are not so trigger happy :)

Comment: @Tom Wouldn't they be down-voting the _questions_ if that was the case? Down-voting random comment is not the correct way regardless. Discussion whether posts are off-topic should be brought up on meta and the Latex tag wiki suggests this has been done before, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stack-overflow.

Comment: Thanks @Marijn for your suggestion. Have tried to align the `&`s and updated the answer.